# How to convert BufferedImage which has a ComponentColorModel to SWT ImageData?

Tags: java, swt, awt, bufferedimage

[This SWT snippet](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet156.java) converts a `BufferedImage` to SWT `ImageData`:

```
static ImageData convertToSWT(BufferedImage bufferedImage) {
    if (bufferedImage.getColorModel() instanceof DirectColorModel) {
        ...
    } else if (bufferedImage.getColorModel() instanceof IndexColorModel) {
        ...
    }
    return null;
}
```

The problem is, there is a third subclass of `ColorModel`: `ComponentColorModel`. And I need to convert an image using this color model. How do I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found [here](http://svn.sharedrecords.org/java/client/Demo/trunk/src/org/sharedrecords/demo/utils/VideoUtils.java) (but mind the patch in crosay's answer!)

```
if (bufferedImage.getColorModel() instanceof ComponentColorModel) {
    ComponentColorModel colorModel = (ComponentColorModel)bufferedImage.getColorModel();

    //ASSUMES: 3 BYTE BGR IMAGE TYPE

    PaletteData palette = new PaletteData(0x0000FF, 0x00FF00,0xFF0000);
    ImageData data = new ImageData(bufferedImage.getWidth(), bufferedImage.getHeight(), colorModel.getPixelSize(), palette);

    //This is valid because we are using a 3-byte Data model with no transparent pixels
    data.transparentPixel = -1;

    WritableRaster raster = bufferedImage.getRaster();
    int[] pixelArray = new int[3];
    for (int y = 0; y < data.height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < data.width; x++) {
            raster.getPixel(x, y, pixelArray);
            int pixel = palette.getPixel(new RGB(pixelArray[0], pixelArray[1], pixelArray[2]));
            data.setPixel(x, y, pixel);
        }
    }
    return data;
```

Answer (score 5):

In Romanov's answer, change the following line:

```
int[] pixelArray = new int[3];
```

with

```
int[] pixelArray = colorModel.getComponentSize();
```

Comment: This also might need a fix for `data.transparentPixel`.